# Is there any way to use /dev/video0 as source for VNC server?

Tags: linux, vnc, webcam, kvm-switch

is there any way to use /dev/video0 as source for VNC server?

I have HDMI grabber connected to USB and I would like to use this video source (/dev/video0) as input for VNC server.

So after I connect to VNC I would like to see HDMI input.

Is it possible? And how?

In time, I would like to add a USB OTG keyboard and cape.

This would give me a cheap KVM.

Comment: Sorry but let me ask you this what do you have connected to the hdmi usb  ? because any ways if you could, i not suggesting it is possible but if you could connect the video from the usd to a vcn server you cant control that machine from the vncviewer it wont more easy run the vnc server on that other machine ? maybe if you explain a more detailed way what do you are trying to do!

Comment: My goal is to create a simple KVM / IPMI for any personal computer.

Comment: If nothing else works, probably playing the capture device on an Xserver started only for that, and then starting also a vnc server on it, would work. But of course you want a better solution, also I am hunting for one.